# PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 on Android API 24 and lower

Tags: android, security, encryption

I'm trying to use Luke Joshua Park [SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) on android. My problem is that PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 is not available for android below API 26. Any way to get around this?

Comment: You can get around it by using something else, like `PBKDF2withHmacSHA1`. Or you can get around it by implementing it yourself, following the spec. I would go with `PBKDF2withHmacSHA1` for API < 26, and `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` for API >= 26. Although SHA1 *should* be secure when used in the HMAC in the PBKDF2 algorithm, it is obsolete and should be removed as soon as possible and everywhere possible.

Comment: Agree with @James. When using SHA-1 as a PRF you should be OK. There are some nuances so be sure you are using `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` correctly to maintain the security of the composite. Also see [Why is HMAC-SHA1 still considered secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26510/10496) and [Is PBKDF2/RFC 2898 broken because SHA1 is broken?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/47517/10496).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android doesn't support `PBKDF2withHmacSHA256` before API 26, but it does support `PBKDF2withHmacSHA1` in older versions.  Unless there is a specific reason you want to use SHA256 as the PBKDF2 hash, there is no harm in changing this.

The algorithms in my repository can be changed relatively easily by adjusting the `PBKDF2_NAME` parameter.  SHA1 is still safe to use with PBKDF2, so you could simply adjust:

```
private final static String PBKDF2_NAME = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
```

To:

```
private final static String PBKDF2_NAME = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
```

In your Android code and in your PHP change:

```
define("PBKDF2_NAME", "sha256");
```

To:

```
define("PBKDF2_NAME", "sha1");
```

Also of note, if you're using this as transport security, you shouldn't be.  You should be using TLS.

Comment: Thank you, Luke. Nice collection examples there. Very helpfull for a noob like me.

Comment: Luke, my intention is also to use your example for PHP.

Comment: @dcd4u2 See my edits.  Pay close attention to my comment about TLS.  You shouldn't be using the code examples as your transport security.